# Hide additional excluding tax price if product is not taxable in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I need to disable displaying the price excluding tax when I set the product without tax.
I made a modification in `price.php` file to add price without VAT.

```
<p class="netto">
    <?php echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax()); ?> netto
</p>
```

If price is not set this "netto price" is still visible in product page.

How can I disable it? Some hooks?

Answer (score 2):

First `woocommerce_price()` function and `get_price_excluding_tax()` method are deprecated and outdated… They are replaced by `wc_price()` and `wc_get_price_excluding_tax()` functions.

Instead of overriding woocommerce template `loop/pride.php` you could use the following code to achieve what you want with this hooked custom function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'conditionally_add_price_excluding_vat ');
function conditionally_add_price_excluding_vat(){
    global $product;

    if( $product->get_tax_status() != 'taxable' ){
        $price_excl_vat = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product);
        echo'<p class="netto">'.wc_price($price_excl_vat).' '. __('netto').'</p>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

> The additional "netto" price will be hidden when the product "**Tax status**" is set to "**None**" on product archive pages.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it yet but I expect something like this should be working:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','custom_remove_loop_price');
function custom_remove_loop_price(){
    global $product;
    if(!$product->price){
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_price',10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the price is still visible. Your function doesn't include price_excluding_tax I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="netto"></p><?php ($product->get_price_excluding_tax() != null) ? echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax()) : echo 0; ?> netto</p>
```

Comment: I've got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /price.php on line 28

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.